# how to use google places Api?

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I use in my app on google places Api with Autocomplete. so I want the user choose some city name Like: London, paris an etc and after in the next Activity the user get list of Activities like: bar, park, shopping and etc. so, my question is:

1. I know I need to take the Lang and Lat I find that from Matohd: `PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi`
   I see in Log the log and lat of the city and it correct but now I need to take the Lang and Lat, How can I take it? and witch method I should use?
2. I see in google api that I should use in Json so, my Link to Json is:

   ```
   String googlePlaceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0&key=AIzaSyByodZEsDBTC-J3brJ39JiYTkqbtJhlSKo";
   ```

so it is the Json correct that I should to work ?

thanks a lot about you'r answers :)

Comment: I think you should proceed like this in the tutorial http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: @cramopy if I need to get list for attractions after the user choose city name on Autocomple, what I should do? I need to get list attractions without Map.